# How to add setTimeout to document.body.addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

this is the javascript code I want to execute with 3 seconds delay. How will it looks like with setTimeout? Thanks in advance!

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
document.body.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
   function myFunction() {
if (window.location.href.indexOf('3124') <= -1) {
window.open('http://example.net/1_of_3/file_5444','mywindow2','width=1600,height=1200');
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
    } 
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.body.addEventListener('click',function(){
   setTimeout(myFunction,3*1000);
 });
function myFunction() {
if (window.location.href.indexOf('3124') <= -1) {
window.open('http://example.net/1_of_3/file_5444','mywindow2','width=1600,height=1200');
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
    } 
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines?

```js
function myFunction() {
 
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(){
  
    console.log('Do Stuff');
  
  });

}
setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
```

```css
.square {

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;

}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="square"></div>

</body>
```